# php call to undefined function from within a class

Tags: php

So, I have a class and from within a function in the class I am trying to call a global function, but I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ()

- the line number the above function refers to is the line in which:

  return get_session_user_id(session_id());

occurs on in the below class function

```
Class Ref {
    function treat_var( $var , $table ) { global $link;
    // do stuff
    return get_session_user_id(session_id());
    }
}
```

The treat_var function is a method in a class and is called by means of:

```
$ref = new Ref;
$ref->treat_var($var,$table);
```

The get_session_user_id function is a global function defined in an included in a file of functions and **works just fine outside of the class** and its code consists of:

```
// this function calls a USER_ID *IF one exists* from a session by using the session ID
function get_session_user_id($sessionID) { global $link;
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT USER_ID AS ID from AAB_SESSIONS WHERE PHPSESSID = '$sessionID'");
        $r = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
        return $r->ID;
}
```

How do I call that function from within the class?

Comment: Please include more code. This part seems to be fine. What line is the code in?

Comment: All the other code functions properly, if I return a string instead of the value derived from the function it returns the string and everything is happy. Still need more code?

Comment: We need more detail.

Comment: Jeff, show which line returns the error.

Comment: I have just expirenced the very same problem with following code inside class function: `$emailAddresses = array_column($recipients, 'email');`
Error is: `Call to undefined function MyPackage\array_column()`

Comment: Unfortunately i don't recall how i corrected the issue, I'll see if i can find it when i get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assure that this global file where function `get_session_user_id()` is defined is loaded before class `Ref` is loaded.

In other words class loading should go in this way:
 1. Include global file which contains impl of `get_session_user_id()`
 2. Load class `Ref`

To check what is going on add this inside the `Ref.php` before the class definition

```
if (!function_exists('get_session_user_id')) {
    die('GLOBAL FILE NOT LOADED and get_session_user_id() function not available!!!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gandra, I like this because rather than having to 'require_once' in several files, I address the root cause of the issue which is the fact that the function is not defined until after the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to call get_session_user_id() and this function is undefined, check, what file with this function is undefined, try to write

```
require_once "...filename with get_session_user_id() function...";
```

at begin of file with your class Ref.